# How to separate legend and chart when having three chart

Tags: angular, charts, highcharts, legend, pie-chart

i have 3 pie charts which have legend in below but in first pie charts there are 10 legend and in second there are only 4 legend then when i give padding to chart to adjust the 10 legend then in second chart 4 legend name stuck at bottom but i want all chart's legend name start from just below the chart not from bottom
how to move legends just below the chart not from bottom

```
            legend: {
                itemStyle: {
                    color: '#10c3d7',
                    lineHeight: '16px'
                },
                itemHoverStyle: {
                    color: '#10c3f3'
                },
                maxHeight: 90,
                itemWidth: 135,
                enabled: true,
          
                align:'left',
                verticalAlign:'bottom',
                navigation: {
                    activeColor: '#3E576F',
                    animation: true,
                    arrowSize: 12,
                    inactiveColor: '#CCC',
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        color: '#333',
                        fontSize: '12px'
                    }
                },
                // maxHeight: 50,
                labelFormatter: function () {
                    // const index = data.findIndex((obj: any) => obj.name === this.name)
                    return this.name;
                }
            },
```

Comment: The description of the problem is incomprehensible. Are you able to improve the question? Add a link to a working demo with the problem. Present what you want to achieve, e.g. in a graphic version. Then it will be easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the **verticalAlign** property in the legend configuration. You can set it to 'bottom' for the first chart and to 'top' for the second chart. And  adjust the **maxHeight** value as needed for both charts.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this code is common for all charts.
data send in *ngfor in html component